# What's the best way to handle and monitor multiple email accounts without using desktop applications such as Outlook?

Tags: gmail, outlook.com, yahoo-mail, aol-mail

I have many email accounts on different domains, on: Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, AOL, and my company email account. I don't like applications that download my emails on my PC such as Outlook. I like to manage them through the browser.

What I am doing now is open a new browser window and open all my email account in its tabs and always keep this window open.

Is there a better way, can you share you experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **Gmail** to manage your emails. Gmail can send & receive emails from other services (like Yahoo,Live or any Pop3 mail). in Gmail just go to *settings>Accounts and Imports* and start importing your mails.

You can use your original mail to reply emails, also you can tag your emails to organize better

Comment: But GMail allows you to add only 5 POP3 accounts.

Answer (score 6):

Simply setup each mail service to forward your mail to one primary email address.  For example I forward everything to my gmail.

On each mail service, I will try to mark all incoming as read and forward a copy to my main mail services.   That way if I ever need to reply from a specific domain I still can.

Comment: and you reply all from gmail?

Comment: Yes unless it's very important that you reply from a specific domain, then in that case you can login to the site in those hopefully rare cases.

Comment: Gmail also allows you to send email using another address, making it appear as though it came from your other address to your recipient.